# Three possible java8 Optional values - how do I cleanly return whichever is present?

Tags: java-8, option-type

I have three java8 Optionals, and want to return whichever one is actually present in a preferred order. It seems like there should be an easy way to chain them like so:

```
return optionalA.orElseIfPresent(optionalB).orElseIfPresent(optionalC);
```

if all three are empty, then an `Optional.empty()` ought to be returned.

the existing orElse and orElseGet are not really up to the task - they must return an actual value, so it's not possible for the remaining fallbacks to be Optionals themselves.

In the worst case I can have a long list of ifPresent() checks, but there just seems like there's a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 7):

```
return Stream.of(optional1, optional2, optional3)
             .filter(Optional::isPresent)
             .map(Optional::get)
             .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 4):

I like JB Nizet's answer (upvoted as well). Alternatively, using only `Optional` (for whatever reason):

```
Optional.ofNullable(
    optionalA.orElse(
        optionalB.orElse(
            optionalC.orElse(null))
        )
    );
```

which falls into indentation/parenthesis madness and I personally do not like.

Comment: The stream answer might be "prettier", but this solution is simpler and more transparent (and, incidentally, more efficient.)